# Get value from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm really new to python, so sorry, if my question is silly. From an sql statement, I fill this dict:

```
config_params = [dict(
    hostname=row[0], syslocation=row[1],
    ipaddress=socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', row[2])),
    netmask=socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', row[3])),
    username=row[4], password=row[5], bri1=row[6], bri2=row[7],
    bri3=row[8], bri4=row[9]) for row in cur.fetchall()
]
```

Now I can print the whole 'config_params' like:

```
print config_params
```

How can I print "only" the value from 'hostname? It didnt't work with 
   print config_params['hostname']

Thanks for helping,

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an exception? If so, show us the exception (with the traceback).

Comment: Won't work means, I got this error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: That error tells you that `config_params` must be a `list`, not a `dict`, which is a useful clue. Which is exactly why you should post the actual error, instead of just saying "it didn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not creating a `dict`, you're creating a `list` of rows, each element of which is a `dict`.

So, to print just the `hostname` for just the first row:

```
print config_params[0]['hostname']
```

Or, to print the hostnames for every row:

```
for row in config_params:
    print row['hostname']
```

… or, if you prefer:

```
print '\n'.join(row['hostname'] for row in config_params)
```

---

Meanwhile, if you're only expecting one row in the first place, just use `fetchone` instead of looping over `fetchall`:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
config_params = dict(
    hostname=row[0], syslocation=row[1],
    ipaddress=socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', row[2])),
    netmask=socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', row[3])),
    username=row[4], password=row[5], bri1=row[6], bri2=row[7],
    bri3=row[8], bri4=row[9])
```

Now you've just got a `dict`.

---

It's also worth noting that many database libraries give you a way to automatically create a dict for each row, using the column names as the keys, or something even fancier. For example, with `sqlite3`:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath, factory=sqlite3.Row)
cur = con.execute('SELECT * FROM Config')
config_params = cur.fetchone()
print config_params['hostname']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of dictionaries, so you'd loop over them:

```
for param in config_params:
    print param['hostname']
```

or access individual items:

```
print config_params[0]['hostname']
```

or use a list comprehension to extract just the hostnames:

```
print [d['hostname'] for d in config_params]
```